# WPF C# Serialize to XML on Binding Validation is correct

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, validation, data-binding

I have a wpf app with an xml Config File.

I made a ViewModel class who is Binded to the MainWindow.xaml, and I'm making some validators using IDataErrorInfo and a ValidationRule class.

What I want is, if the user changes a value, and the value passes the validation, the config class becomes serialized to xml.

For the save I have a class extension:

```
public static class ConfiguracionExtension
{
    public static void Save(this Configuration configXML)
    {
        string ConfigPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "config.xml";
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
        Stream writer = new FileStream(ConfigPath, FileMode.Create);
        ns.Add("", "");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, configXML, ns);
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

The configuration class looks like:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("configuration")]
public class Configuration : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _minute;
    [XmlElement]
    public int minute
    {
        get
        {
            return _minute;
        }
        set
        {
            _minute = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("minute");
        }
    }
    public static Configuration Load()
    {
        string ConfigPath= AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "config.xml";
        if (File.Exists(ConfigPath))
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer _s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
                return (Configuration)_s.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(ConfigPath));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Auxiliar.writeError(ex.ToString());
                return new Configuration();
            }
        }
        else
            return new Configuration();
    }
    public Configuracion()
    {
        minutes = 60;
    }
    #region IDataErrorInfo Members
    public string Error
    {
        get { return String.Empty; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            String errorMessage = String.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "minute":
                    if (minute < 1)
                    {
                        errorMessage = "minutes can't be less than 1";
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return errorMessage;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and the validation rule looks like:

```
public class MinutesValidation : ValidationRule
{
    private int _min;
    public int Minimum
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set { _min = value; }
    }
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int minute;
        Boolean noIllegalChars;
        noIllegalChars = int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out minute);

        if (value.ToString().Length < 1)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Value can't be empty");
        }
        else if (noIllegalChars == false)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Ilegal Character");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not clear what the problem is. Why cant you just call your Save in setter of changed property?

Comment: I get a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException exception, I think I can call to serialize on the set, because the set is called on deserialize. Also, the set is called every time the property recive data, but the validation is only called when the user inputs data.

Comment: If you need to distinguish whether property changed by user or programmatically you probably have to had two properties. One is core property, and other is just for binding with validation and the second wraps the first.

Comment: So, there's no way to call the save funcion when the ValidationResult is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I Solved, but if anyone gets a better option I'll be very greatful.

What I've done is on the config file I added a loaded boolean who starts on false, and I added a condition to the save function to work only when the loaded is true.

The config class now is like this:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("configuration")]
public class Configuration : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _minute;
    [XmlElement]
    public int minute
    {
        get
        {
            return _minute;
        }
        set
        {
            _minute = value;
            this.Save();
            OnPropertyChanged("minute");
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool loaded;

    public static Configuration Load()
    {
    string ConfigPath= AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "config.xml";
    if (File.Exists(ConfigPath))
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer _s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
            var tempConf = (Configuracion)_s.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(ConfigPath));
            tempConf.loaded = false;
            return tempConf;
        }
        [...]
    }
    public Configuracion()
    {
        loaded = false;
        minutes = 60;
    }
    [...]
}
```

I added a loaded event to the main window, and when it's fired it sets the loaded property to true.